# Umbraco problem getting chilld properties

Tags: model-view-controller, umbraco

I have Umbraco Content List containing multiple Umbraco Content pages. When I try to find some content page properties like Page Title or Heading or bodyText I'm getting  `"The function evaluation requires all threads to run.`". Here is my code.

```
@using Umbraco.Web
@using Umbraco.Web.Mvc

@{
    Layout = "T";
}
@{

    var UContentList = Model.Content.Children;

    var SContentList = new List<MyProgram.Models.MyContent>();

    foreach (var uContent in UContentList)
    {
        var SContent = new IMyProgram.Models.MyContent(
            uContent.pageTitle.ToString(),
            uContent.contentExcerpt.ToString()
            );
        SContentList.Add(SContent);
    }
```

Please help how do I get the values from these properties

Comment: The code looks like it'd work, but I'd highly recommend not doing this in the view. Move this code to your controller, and you may find it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it. First need to debug and do this:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/

Then here is the source:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@using Umbraco.Web
@using Umbraco.Web.Mvc

@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;

@{
    /**/
    Layout = "";

}
@{

    var UContentList = Model.Content.Children();

    var SContentList = new List<MyProgram.Models.MyContent>();

    foreach (var uContent in UContentList)
    {
        var SContent = new MyProgram.Models.MyContent(
            uContent.GetPropertyValue("pageTitle").ToString(),
            uContent.GetPropertyValue("contentExcerpt").ToString(),
            uContent.Url.ToString()
            );
        SContentList.Add(SContent);

    }
```

The difference is the @inherits and @using ContentModels.